# java bluetooth connection with android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluecove

i've beeing working on a project in bluetooth with java on eclispe.
    im using a code i found on the web and now im trying to study it in order to be able to make a few changes .
    the code complies and the are no erros . 
    but it seems to not work , 
    it prints out

```
"BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on winsock
04c6093b00001000800000805f9b34fb
waiting for connection..." and doesnt continue .

ive beeing using this guys code  in the link below 
http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

here is the java file code 


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnectionNotifier;

public class WaitThread implements Runnable{

    /** Constructor */
    public WaitThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        waitForConnection();        
    }

    /** Waiting for connection from devices */
    private void waitForConnection() {
        // retrieve the local Bluetooth device object
        LocalDevice local = null;

        StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
        StreamConnection connection = null;

        // setup the server to listen for connection
        try {
            local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

            UUID uuid = new UUID("04c6093b00001000800000805f9b34fb", false);
            System.out.println(uuid.toString());

            String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=RemoteBluetooth";
            notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);
        } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Bluetooth is not turned on.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // waiting for connection
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("waiting for connection...");
                connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
                Thread processThread = new Thread(new ProcessConnectionThread(connection));
                processThread.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


really appriciate all the help !
thankss
```

Comment: Where is your client code ?

Comment: i used the code from here ..https://github.com/luugiathuy/Remote-Bluetooth-Android/tree/master/RemoteBluetooth/src/com/luugiathuy/apps/remotebluetooth

Comment: Have changed UUID part in server and client ? Make sure uuid.toString() part in server is giving same output as UUID used in you android client part.